# em.persist(t) --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager, persist

I am new to hibernate, I have this method :
private EntityManager em;

```
@Override
public void save(T t) {
    if(t != null) {
        em.persist(t);
    }
}
```

I did not understand what this expression mean :

"em.persist(t)"  
    An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 2):

EntityManager's persist method makes instance managed and persistent.

As documented in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29), `persist` method throws `IllegalArgumentException` if argument is not an entity. Typical reasons for object not being entity are missing [@Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) annotation and/or missing entry for entity in persistence.xml.